# Cost of calling a function or not in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Compare:

```
if (myVariable) {
    doSomething()
}

function doSomething ()
{
    // Work goes here
}
```

vs

```
doSomething();

function doSomething()
{
    if (myVariable) {
        // Work goes here
    }
}
```

ie My question is whether it's faster to do the check outside of the function and avoid a context switch (I think that's the right term) ) or just do it inside the function because it makes such a minor difference?

Cheers.

Comment: Great Question! If myVariable is not always available the second example will only work if you give the variable as an argument to the function, I don't know if this is wisely. On the other hand you prevent certain mistakes. In my opinion: If myVariable must always be true to execute the function, use example two. If it's optional use example one.

Comment: If you're asking about the cost of calling a function, then yes there is some cost, but how much will depend on the JavaScript implementation. There is less cost in newer implementations, but the cost is still there.

Comment: Look after the pounds and the pennies will look after themselves :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[It Just Doesn't Matter](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) (although the first method avoids some work so it should faster, but by an amount which is probably less than statistical noise).

What really matters is which method best represents the logic. Rule of thumb is that every statement in a function should be on about the same level of abstraction. Is the conditional expression more or less abstract than the function call?

Comment: I understand and agree with your point that it doesn't matter. But this question has a correct answer, and "It just doesn't matter" is not the correct answer. I wish your answer would state clearly the correct answer, and use the "doesn't matter" point as an afterthought. It really doesn't matter in 99.99% of the cases, but if you happen to be trying to create a Node web server capable of handling millions of requests per second, it would probably matter to some degree.

Comment: If you're handling millions of requests per second, then this is not your bottleneck. The correct answer is "follow the rules of best design, not the rules of best optimization."

Answer (score 1):

It would be faster to do it outside because making a function call every time will be slightly slower than checking first and then calling the function.

But why bother? No one is going to notice a function call vs what the function call is actually doing. Inefficient DOM selectors that make your code have to hunt and peck through a huge tree structure for a few needles in the haystack are a far greater threat to performance.

Comment: A little context: Normally I'd agree that it's a really minuscule difference that normally isn't worth being concerned about, but the code is a library that other people will use, so it really needs not to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Actually, forget that. I've just read the article and in summary: I'm worrying about nada.

Answer (score 1):

It's negligible; the differences in performance are miniscule, and browsers seem to handle this differently:

Edit: There is indeed a difference in performance: most browsers execute Method 1 slightly quicker.

```
//Method 1:

var t1 = Date.now();

myVariable = true;

for(var i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {



    function doSomething ()
    {
        Math.sin(Math.cos(0));
    }

    if (myVariable) {
        doSomething()
    }

    myVariable = !myVariable;
}

console.log(Date.now() - t1);







//Method 2:

var t1 = Date.now();

myVariable = true;

for(var i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {

    function doSomething()
    {
        if (myVariable) {
            Math.sin(Math.cos(0));
        }
    }


    doSomething();

    myVariable = !myVariable;

}

console.log(Date.now() - t1);





//Results:
//Safari:   About the same, former was slightly quicker
//Firefox:  Former was quicker
//Chrome:   About the same, latter was somewhat quicker
//Opera:    Executed the former quicker
```

Comment: Your `myVariable` is always `true`, so you're not really measuring the cost of calling a function (because it's always being called).

Comment: Your test is poor because you're forcing the poor interpreter to _recreate_ the same function over and over millions of times.  Hence you're measuring the overhead of function _creation_, not function _invocation_.

Comment: I modified the above code into a http://jsperf.com/test-of-function-call-overhead which i think says that the first method is faster than the second by like 15% on Chrome 12

Comment: @Dan D. Wow, it's quite a positive difference on my computer; the former is 50% faster! (Chrome 16.0.912.75 on Mac OS X 10.6.8)

Answer (score 0):

I find that the second method makes for more maintainable and readable code.  This incurs very little overhead.

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. Depends on the circumstances, no?

Comment: Please be more precise: the question is about performance differences, not about readability or maintainability