# boolean in a method vs boolean before calling method?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, action, conditional-statements

So I want to check for example if my ev3 robot is connected before doing actions.

What's the better way, this

```
if (ev3Connected)
    doStuff();

private void doStuff() {
    //stuff
}
```

or this?

```
doStuff();

private void doStuff() {
    if (ev3Connected) {
        //stuff 
    }
}
```

Or is there just zero difference at all?

Comment: It totally depends on what you are trying to do. If you always need the condition to be checked before doing `//stuff`, put it in the method. If you want to be able to invoke the method without checking, you have to do the check outside the method.

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9019221/3143670)

Comment: Irrespective of language, the question is same. Hence marked as dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I'd go for your first option.

```
if (ev3Connected)
    doStuff();

private void doStuff() {
    //stuff
}
```

I do this because the higher level methods should always be easier to read. Alternatively you could rename doStuff() to doStuffIfEvoConnected() but you can kinda taste that the if statement is clearer.

This has the benefit that someone debugging your code will know that doStuff() wasn't executed when stepping through the code even without entering the method.

If it is absolutely imperative that doStuff() is never entered unless ev3Connected then you should throw an exception from inside the method whilst still having the if check in parent code. I could imagine that doStuff could work if for example ev4Connected instead.